# Loop through Knockout observable array of objects with observable properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

In my app I need to loop through my Knockout observable array of objects with observable properties. This is so I can post each object back to the server.

I can access my model but I can not access the child elements, which I would like to post back to the server.

My client code is

```
self.postAllReqs = function(self) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    var model = ko.toJSON(self.Reqs); // convert to json
    for (var item in model) {

        ajaxHelper(reqsUri, 'POST', item).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
    })
}
```

}

How do I access the child element please?

Extract of my View Model

```
function ReqsTest(rt) {
rt = rt || {};
var self = this;
self.id = ko.observable(rt.ID || 0);
self.requisition = ko.observable(rt.Requisition || "");
self.reqnStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqnStatus || "");
self.dateReqnRaised = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaised|| null);
self.reqnValue = ko.observable(rt.ReqnValue || null);
self.approvedValue = ko.observable(rt.ApprovedValue || null);
self.originator = ko.observable(rt.Originator || "");
self.origName = ko.observable(rt.OrigName || "");
self.origEmail = ko.observable(rt.OrigEmail || "");
self.line = ko.observable(rt.Line || 0.00);
self.indx = ko.observable(rt.INDX || 0);
self.dateReqnRaisedL = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaisedL || null);
self.reqStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqStatus || "");
//self.reqBackground = ko.observable(rt.ReqBackground || "");


//Computed observables
self.reqBackground = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") { return "card-heading bg-success text-white"; }
    else if (status == "D") { return "card heading bg-secondary"; }
    else if (status == "R") { return "card heading bg-warning"; }
    else if (status == "E") { return "card heading bg-danger"; }
    else {
        return "card-heading bg-primary text-white";
    }
})
self.reqStatusLabel = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") { return "Approved"; }
    else if (status == "D") { return "Declined - put on hold"; }
    else if (status == "R") { return "Routing On"; }
    else if (status == "E") { return "Erase On Syspro"; }
    else {
        return "Awaiting Approval";
    }
})

self.approvalBtn = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") { return "css: button btn-secondary "; }
    else {
        return "btn btn-success ";
    }
})

self.approvalBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "W") { return "Approve"; }
    else {
        return "UnApprove";
    }
})



self.declineBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "D") { return "UnDecline"; }
    else {
        return "Decline";
    }
})

self.deleteBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "E") { return "Restore"; }
    else {
        return "Erase";
    }
})

// Functions
//show details alert
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    $(".alert").removeClass("in").show();
    $(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(2000);
});
```

}

```
function ReqsViewModel (){
    var self = this;
    self.Reqs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.error = ko.observable();

    var reqsUri = '/api/ReqsTests/';

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}

function getAllReqs() {
    ajaxHelper(reqsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        // Build the ReqsTest objects
        var reqs = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (rt) {
            return new ReqsTest(rt);
        });
        self.Reqs(reqs);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell with the code provided, there is nothing calling the getAllReqs as its a private function withing the ReqsViewModel.

I'm not exactly clear on what your issue is, so I have created a quick demo using your example code to show how you can interact with items in the array.

```js
var app = {};
function ReqsTest(rt, saveItemFn) {
  rt = rt || {};
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(rt.ID || 0);
  self.requisition = ko.observable(rt.Requisition || "");
  self.reqnStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqnStatus || "");
  self.dateReqnRaised = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaised || null);
  self.reqnValue = ko.observable(rt.ReqnValue || null);
  self.approvedValue = ko.observable(rt.ApprovedValue || null);
  self.originator = ko.observable(rt.Originator || "");
  self.origName = ko.observable(rt.OrigName || "");
  self.origEmail = ko.observable(rt.OrigEmail || "");
  self.line = ko.observable(rt.Line || 0.00);
  self.indx = ko.observable(rt.INDX || 0);
  self.dateReqnRaisedL = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaisedL || null);
  self.reqStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqStatus || "");
  //self.reqBackground = ko.observable(rt.ReqBackground || "");


  //Computed observables
  self.reqBackground = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") {
      return "card-heading bg-success text-white";
    } else if (status == "D") {
      return "card heading bg-secondary";
    } else if (status == "R") {
      return "card heading bg-warning";
    } else if (status == "E") {
      return "card heading bg-danger";
    } else {
      return "card-heading bg-primary text-white";
    }
  })
  self.reqStatusLabel = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") {
      return "Approved";
    } else if (status == "D") {
      return "Declined - put on hold";
    } else if (status == "R") {
      return "Routing On";
    } else if (status == "E") {
      return "Erase On Syspro";
    } else {
      return "Awaiting Approval";
    }
  })

  self.approvalBtn = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "A") {
      return "css: button btn-secondary ";
    } else {
      return "btn btn-success ";
    }
  })

  self.approvalBtnLbl = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "W") {
      return "Approve";
    } else {
      return "UnApprove";
    }
  })
  self.approve = function() {
    if (self.reqStatus() == 'W') {
      self.reqStatus("A");

    } else {
      self.reqStatus("W");
    }
    saveItemFn(self);
  }


  self.declineBtnLbl = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "D") {
      return "UnDecline";
    } else {
      return "Decline";
    }
  })

  self.deleteBtnLbl = ko.computed(function() {
    // get variable 
    var status = self.reqStatus();
    if (status == "E") {
      return "Restore";
    } else {
      return "Erase";
    }
  })

  // Functions
  //show details alert
  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".alert").removeClass("in").show();
    $(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(2000);
  });
}

function dataService(serviceUrl) {
  var url = serviceUrl;

  function getData() {
    // do ajax call here
    return {
      done: function(fn) {
        return fn(app.externalData);
      }
    }
 }
    function saveItem(item) {
      // add posting to server here.
      alert("Saving item: " + item.id());
    }

    return {
      getData: getData,
      saveItem: saveItem,
    };
  
}

function ReqsViewModel(dataService) {
  var reqsUri = 'api/ReqsTests/';
  var self = this;
  self.Reqs = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.error = ko.observable();
  self.getAllReqs = getAllReqs;

  function getAllReqs() {
    dataService.getData().done(function(data) {
      // Build the ReqsTest objects
      var reqs = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(rt) {
        return new ReqsTest(rt, dataService.saveItem);
      });
      self.Reqs(reqs);
    });

  }
}
app.dataService = dataService;

app.externalData = [{
  ID: 1,
  Requisition: "Requisition 1",
  ReqnStatus: "A",
  DateReqnRaised: "2019-01-01T11:00:00+11:00",
  ReqnValue: 200.24,
  ApprovedValue: 200,
  Originator: "Slartibartfast",
  OrigName: "Requisition 1",
  OrigEmail: "test@test.com",
  Line: 1.1,
  INDX: 1,
  DateReqnRaisedL: "2019-01-01T11:00:00+11:00",
  ReqStatus: "A"
}, {
  ID: 2,
  Requisition: "Requisition 2",
  ReqnStatus: "W",
  DateReqnRaised: "2019-01-02T11:00:00+11:00",
  ReqnValue: 300.24,
  ApprovedValue: 300,
  Originator: "Slartibartfast",
  OrigName: "Requisition 2",
  OrigEmail: "test@test.com",
  Line: 2.2,
  INDX: 2,
  DateReqnRaisedL: "2019-01-02T11:00:00+11:00",
  ReqStatus: "W"
}];

var vm = new ReqsViewModel(app.dataService("/api/reqs/"));
vm.getAllReqs();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Requistion</th>
      <th>Raised</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Reqs">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: requisition"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: dateReqnRaised"></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: approvalBtn, text: approvalBtnLbl, click: approve">Approve</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```